# Unity: Recalculate mesh on GPU

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was searching in the web for some time, but couldn't find a good answer for my current problem: In unity a visible object consists of a mesh. In OpenGL terms, a mesh is a VertexBuffer that is transmitted, ideally once, to the GPU and then feed into the vertex shader.

And now, at some given point I want to recalculate the given mesh on the GPU. For example, if my VertexBuffer has space for 200 `Vector3<float>` that are part of a Cube, I want to do a call to a ComputeShader(?) that updates every `Vector3<float>` so that the mesh is now a sphere.

I know I could reassign the mesh using the CPU, but in my scenario thats too slow.

So the question is, how can i pass a VertexBuffer or Mesh into a ComputeShader in unity? I would like to directly modifye the VertexBuffer.

Thanks for ideas, ressources, hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute Shaders are simple to setup.

write a Compute shader like this

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

#define thread_group_size_x 4
#define thread_group_size_y 4

//A struct that simple holds a position
struct PositionStruct
{
    float3 pos;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<PositionStruct> output;

[numthreads(thread_group_size_x,thread_group_size_y,1)]

void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
   int idx = id.x + id.y * thread_group_size_x * 32;
   float spacing = 1.0;

   float3 pos = float3(id.x*spacing, id.y*spacing, id.z*spacing);

   pos = UpdateVertex(pos,idx);

   output[idx].pos = pos;
}

float3 UpdateVertex(float3 p, int idx)
{
    //Do your stuff here
    return p;
}
```

Now Create the C# file that dispatches this compute file.

```
public class ComputeShaderScript: MonoBehaviour
{
public Shader shader;
public ComputeShader computeShader;

private ComputeBuffer outputBuffer;
private int _kernel;
private Material material;

void Start()
{
 RunShader();
}

void RunShader()
{
  _Kernal = computeShader.FindKernal("CSMain");

  vector3 Array = new vector3[200];
  outputBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(Array.Length, 12); //Output buffer  contains      vertices (float3 = Vector3 -> 12 bytes)
  outputbuffer.SetData(Array);

  computeShader.SetBuffer(_Kernal,"output",outputBuffer);

  computeShader.Dispatch(_Kernal,array.Length,1,1);

  vector3 data= new vector3[200];
  outputbuffer.GetData(data);

  buffer.Dispose();

  material.SetPass(0);
  material.SetBuffer("buf_Points", outputBuffer);
  Graphics.DrawProcedural(MeshTopology.Points, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Is this step `vector3 data= new vector3[200]; outputbuffer.GetData(data);`  necessary? It reads like "copy the data back to the cpu". But `outputbuffer` is my openGL VertexBuffer so to say? So if i know the length of the buffer i could hand it directly to the mesh without copying back to cpu?

Comment: In order to get your data you have to have the buffer copy the resulting data from itself to a new location in CPU RAM. This is done using the GetData method after dispatch is called.

Comment: Okay, one last question. Where is "buf_Points" coming from, in the call to `SetBuffer()`.

Comment: you can skip that part metrial.SetBuffer(string name,ComputeBuffer value) where name is the Property name. "buf_Points" is property name defined in the shader. that is if you have written the shader to draw it

Comment: So it works. Very nice. I come up with one last question, i cannot find any information about it: Why is it `int idx = id.x + id.y * thread_group_size_x * 32;` Why `*32`. Where is it coming from.

Comment: You do not have to bring the updated vertex data back to the CPU - it's not only unnecessary but is also a huge waste of time. It takes forever to move data back and to the GPU. Instead you should be able to just bind the same buffer onto your shader after the compute dispatch.